# in CodenameOne, What could cause my Back Button to not be functional (can't be pressed)?

Tags: codenameone

TL/DR: the Back command soft-key on iOS can no longer be pressed in simulator or device (but on simulator I can press "esc" to trigger a "back" operation).  This used to work in older builds.

Details:
In my beforeVideoScreen method (for the "Video Screen" form built in the (Old) Gui Builder) on iOS the following code places a "Back" button on the bottom of the screen.   For some reason it recently stopped working in a recent update of the CN1 Libraries and plugin (I'm on plugin 4.4 and the most up to date CN1 Libraries).  the button can no longer be pressed.

```
@Override
protected void beforeVideoScreen(Form f) {

    final Form vidForm = f;

    final Command backCommand = Command.create("Back", null, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Log.p("Back pressed in Video screen");

            //stop the video playing by blanking the browser object
            browser.setPage("<html><body></body></html>", null);

            //remove the browser from the page before going back to deal with android "double-back" bug
            vidForm.removeComponent(browser);

            //add an image to make the blank screen look better as it slides out
            vidForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Label(fetchResourceFile().getImage("SplashScreenLogo.jpg")));

            //perform the back operation - pop the video screen off the back stack
            back();
        }
    });
    f.removeAllCommands();

    f.addCommand(backCommand);

    f.setBackCommand(backCommand);

...

}
```

Any idea what I may have done that could prevent the back button being pressed?   I have tried adding additional commands to see if they can be pressed but they cannot be pressed either.

Comment: Is this old code that predates the global toolbar? Did you enable global toolbar? What's the command behavior setting?

Comment: What is a global toolbar?  it probably predates the global toolbar.  it's a few years old and had been working until recently.  is this way of adding commands deprecated now and in need of changing?

Comment: It's discouraged but should still work. Unfortunately since we don't test it as heavily things can fail without us noticing them. What's the value of your command behavior constant (or in the code)? How does this look? (screenshot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without switching to the Toolbar across all my forms I Was stuck using a kludgey workaround.

I had originally set the "CommandBehaviour" theme constant to "Touch" as it gave the interface I was looking for: A "Back" button across the bottom of a screen.

Apparently that was deprecated.

The easiest way to fix this was to add a "Back" button manually to the South pane of my Form's BorderLayout and assign it the same command as the BackCommand

```
final Command backCommand = Command.create("Back", null, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Log.p("Back pressed in Video screen");
        //stop the video playing by blanking the browser object
        browser.setPage("<html><body></body></html>", null);

        //remove the browser from the page before going back to deal with android "double-back" bug
        vidForm.removeComponent(browser);

        //add an image to make the blank screen look better as it slides out
        vidForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Label(fetchResourceFile().getImage("SplashScreenLogo.jpg")));

        //perform the back operation - pop the video screen off the back stack
        back();
    }
});
f.removeAllCommands();
f.setBackCommand(backCommand);

Button backButton = new Button(backCommand);

f.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, backButton);
...
```